# Combining parent() and children() selectors in JQuery

Tags: jquery

I currently have the following series of JQuery selectors:

`$(this).parent().parent().children('a').children('img').attr('src')`

It works just fine but is there a more compact way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Here's my HTML structure:

```
<div class="preview">
    <a><img src="#"></a>
    <div class="info">
        <div class="item">This is where we start.</div>
    <div>
</div>
```

Comment: there always is.  It just depends on your HTML structure. Can you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: Okay, I've posted the HTML (simplified).

Comment: I think the quickest way this could be done without worrying about performance hits would be `$(this).parents('.preview').find('img').attr('src')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work given your initial condition, regardless of the specific markup:'

```
$(this).parent().siblings('a').children('img').attr('src')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
$(this).closest('.preview').find('a img').attr('src')
```

[Closest Docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/) | 
[Find Docs](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 0):

With that HTML, one way would be:

```
$(this).parents(".preview").find("a img").attr("src");
```

You could also easily:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children("img").attr("src");
```

Although, if you can make use of HTML5, my suggestion would be to add a data-ref to the start element div as follows:

```
<div class="item" data-ref="#imgID-1">This is where we start.</div>
// and of course add an id to the img
<img id="imgID-1" src="blah.png" />
```

Then you can easily recall as:

```
var source = $($(this).data("ref")).attr("src");
```